# how to minus two times while time is in string and 24 hours format

Tags: javascript

I have two time strings and I want subtract them and want to get total minutes.

```
                var firstHour = dateArray[0];
                var firstMinutes = dateArray[1];
                var firstSec = dateArray[2];
                var secondHour = dateArrayEnd[0];
                var secondMinutes = dateArrayEnd[1];
                var secondSec = dateArrayEnd[2];
                console.log("Hour Differece", secondHour -firstHour);
                console.log("Mins Differece",firstMinutes - secondMinutes);
                console.log("Second Differece",firstSec - secondSec );
                var hours = secondHour -firstHour;
                var mins= secondMinutes -firstMinutes;
                var totalMins = (hours *60) + mins;
                console.log("total mins",totalMins);
```

this is providing me the total minutes, but the problem is if the first hour is 23 and end time 3, then it will show 20 but actually difference should be 4.
so how can i minus two times??

Comment: "first hour is 23 and end time 3, then it will show 20 but actually difference should be 3" -- I dont know what kind of subtraction you are trying to do where the difference between 3 and 23 is 3

Comment: @Craicerjack.. time is 0:00 after 23:59

Comment: @Craicerjack
23:00 pm and morning 3:00am (difference is?? 4 hours

Comment: It would help to know what's in your dateArray.

This link could be useful (found in another stackoverflow post)

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/calculating-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript.html#fbid=FtYaYOzrTUK

Comment: why dont you convert them to js Dates and then just subtract them to get the number of milliseconds then multiply 1000, job done

Comment: but if you must stick with strings then I guess you should stick this in, `if(secondHour < firstHour) secondHour += 24` before you do the hour subtraction.